# Why is my video RAM 256MB when it should be 2GB?

Tags: graphics, ati

I upgraded from ATI Radeon HD 5670 256MB VRAM (or whatsoever) to ATI Radeon HD 6450 2GB VRAM. When I was booting my PC it seemed quite slow. I began to panic when I saw 256 MB in PCI devices listed in 'hardinfo'.

Comment: I take you haven't installed the propietary drivers? does hwinfo shows the same?

Comment: Maybe it's a faulty card.. does other OS shows the same behavior ?.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the CCSM (Config Compiz Settings Manager) OpenGL-> Uncheck "Sych with VBlank"